# WooCommerce Shopify Theme Product Order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having an issue with a theme that I bought. I need the theme to order in ASC by date like woocommerce normally has it:

```
[recent_products per_page="12" columns="4" orderby="date" order="asc"]
```

But, this theme needs to use their own "page builder template" to allow the products to show up nicely. Yet I need them to still be in the order of creation. I am needing help to find out how to solve this problem. The site is: http://randomlyopen.com/martinjenkins/

The page that I think would need to be modified is shop-block.php with the following code is here: http://pastebin.com/tGs3WAUL

Comment: PS - The theme is Shopsy http://themeforest.net/item/shopsy-responsive-ecommerce-theme/6044343

Comment: I tried changing the pastebin to: <?php $catTerms = get_terms('product_cat', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'DESC', )); ?> and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Near line 102 we did this:

```
<ul class="products">
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 50,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
```

And it worked perfectly!